# How to create this multiple scatter plots in mclust package in r?

Tags: r, mclust

I use MCLUST and specifically specify K=3 clusters, with the covariance matrix type is VII.

```
library(mclust)
mc <- Mclust(iris[,-5],  G = 2)
```

How to create a figure like below? It's from my textbook: Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis by Johnson and Wichern. Notice that this figure has 2 clusters (squares and triangles) in each figure. So the textbook has a mistake here. The textbook used 2 clusters.

[image]

Comment: That is a pairplot. That specific plot is `pairs(iris %>% select(!Species))`. As it stands, it has nothing to do with the clustering results.

Comment: I try to run your code. But R returns: Error in iris %>% select(!Species) : could not find function "%>%"

Comment: install and load the tidyverse package.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can run your code. It's very similar, almost the same. But it lacks cluster characteristic. If you look at the tetxbook figure carefully (zoom in), you'll find in each figure, there are different marks of points (triangle, square) to represent clusters.

Comment: Didn't realize that. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to modify the shape based on cluster assignment, you can do so through the use of `pch`. Using your data:

```
pairs(mc$data, pch = mc$classification)
```

[image]

If you want to change the shapes, you can map the classification assignment to the desired [shape](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/points).

Comment: Thanks. You might also help me in this follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340077/how-to-create-this-scatter-plot-with-clusters-in-mclust-package-in-r